# Creating a new layer with features derived from others from an existing layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, linestring

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover.
I have a point layer and I want to create a new line layer with features derived from the first one, using the following code

```
make_line(
 -- using an array of points placed around the original
array_foreach(
-- list of angles for placing the projected points (every 90°)
array:=generate_series( 0, 360, 90 ),
-- translate the point 20 units in the given direction (angle)
expression:=project( $geometry, distance:=20, azimuth:=radians( @element ) )
 )
)
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a new symbol layer / [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) / Linestring and paste your expression. This is for visualization only. To get actual geoemtries, use [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for the differences](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

[image]

Comment: That "Geometry by expression" is what I needed and it was simply in the toolbox.